# how to compare string value "attribute" in ATL eclipse

Tags: java, string, eclipse

In my source ecore model I have **Eclass** named "TASK" which have one **Eattribute** called "name" with type of string.

instance of name will contain two main words e.g.,

" Send Order"

I'm going to transform each word to different target elements.

So are there any available comparing string functions in ATL that can checks the same attribute value, or can separate two words based on whitespace among them?